# How to cast all columns of a DataFrame (with Nested StructTypes and nested ArrayType) to string in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
root
|-- channelGrouping: string (nullable = true)
|-- clientId:string (nullable = true)
|-- customDimensions: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |--index: Long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
|-- date: string (nullable = true)
|-- device: struct (nullable =true)
|    |-- browser:string(nullable = true)
|    |-- browserSize: Int (nullable = true)
|    |-- browserVersion:string (nullable = true)
|    |-- deviceCategory: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- flashVersion: string (nullable = true)
|    |--isMobile: boolean (nullable = true)
|    |-- javaEnabled: boolean (nullable = true)



val structCastExpression1 = df.schema
.filter(_.dataType.isInstanceOf[StructType])
.map(c=> (c.name, c.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].map(_.name)))
.map{ case (col, sub) =>  s"""cast($col as struct${sub.map{ c => 
s"$c:string" }.mkString("<" , "," , ">")} ) as $col"""}  
//List(cast(s1 as struct<x:string,y:string> ) as s1,   //     cast(s2
as struct<u:string,v:string> ) as s2)

val otherColumns = df.schema
.filterNot(_.dataType.isInstanceOf[StructType])
.map( c=> s""" cast(${c.name} as string) as ${c.name} """)   //List(" cast(id as string) as id ", " cast(d as string) as d")

//original columns   val originalColumns = df.columns

// Union both the expressions into one big expression   val
finalExpression = otherColumns.union(structCastExpression1)   //
List(" cast(id as string) as id ",   //      " cast(d as string) as d
",   //      cast(s1 as struct<x:string,y:string> ) as s1,   //     
cast(s2 as struct<u:string,v:string> ) as s2 )

// Use `selectExpr` to pass the expression

df.selectExpr(finalExpression : _*)
.select(originalColumns.head, originalColumns.tail: _*)
.printSchema
```

After i am using this

```
root
|-- channelGrouping: string (nullable = true)
|-- clientId:string (nullable = true)
|-- customDimensions: string (nullable = true)
|-- date: string (nullable = true)
|-- device: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- browser: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- browserSize: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- browserVersion:string (nullable = true)
|    |-- deviceCategory: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- flashVersion: string (nullable = true)
|    |--isMobile: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- javaEnabled: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- language: string (nullable = true)
```

expected out put is

```
root
|-- channelGrouping: string (nullable = true)
|-- clientId:string (nullable = true)
|-- customDimensions: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |--index: String (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
|-- date: string (nullable = true)
|-- device: struct (nullable =true)
|    |-- browser:string(nullable = true)
|    |-- browserSize: String (nullable = true)
|    |-- browserVersion:string (nullable = true)
|    |-- deviceCategory: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- flashVersion: string (nullable = true)
|    |--isMobile: boolean (nullable = true)
|    |-- javaEnabled: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Hello there ! What have you tried ?

Comment: Actually that is nested json file how to convert all column datatypes to string using s

Comment: Please reformat your question. It's not readable at it's current state.

Comment: Cloud help me please